# Disallow files without extension

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I am currently doing this with htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^view$ view.php [L]
```

And I link to `/view` without the extension and it works fine.
But how do I disable robots from indexing `/view`? in the `robots.txt` I put

```
Disallow: /view.php
Disallow: /view
```

When I go into webmaster tools and I fetch as google. I can fetch the `mydomain.com/view`, which is not suppose to happen, but when I try to fetch `mydomain.com/view.php` it says blocked by robots.txt, which is good.

How can I block access to `/view` from robots?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Disallow: /view
```

should block URLs like:

- `example.com/view`
- `example.com/view/`
- `example.com/view/foobar`
- `example.com/view.php`
- `example.com/viewer`

As you see, you wouldn't need `Disallow: /view.php` at all.

So there seems to be a different problem. Was this a recent change? Maybe Google cached an older variant of your robots.txt. I don't know this fetching tool, but maybe the problem is related to the redirect? I'd guess that the Google fetching tool should be redirected to `/view.php`.